# What's really good about .NET Framework 3.5 (except LINQ)?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5

I'm moving from .NET Framework 2.0 to 3.5.

I'm not a big fan of LINQ. So beside of that and "extensions" what should I do know and take advantage of in .NET Framework 3.5?

Comment: You don't like LINQ to SQL? LINQ to XML? LINQ to Objects? The LINQ language features? Most of the extension methods included in 3.5 are part of LINQ.

Comment: I was referring to LINQ to objects I suppose, I don't really care about LINQ to SQL and LINQ to XML, never use them really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the following two articles:

- [What's New in the .NET Framework Version 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332048.aspx)
- [What's New in the .NET Framework Version 3.5 SP1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713697.aspx)

and if you're using C#, here's a list of new language features:

- [What's New in Visual C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383815.aspx)

and finally for the ASP.NET developer:

- [What's New in ASP.NET and Web Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s57a598e.aspx)

There are so many new features, I'm sure you'll find one you like ;-)

Personally, I really like LINQ. It allows to rewrite a lot of code in a much more readable form, e.g. lots of multi-line foreach loops can be replaced with a simple (readable) LINQ version.

Answer (score 14):

Lambdas, Type Inferance.. most of the underlying things that were created to support LINQ.

Why are you not a fan of LINQ?

EDIT: AS a followup, when I say LINQ I am not talking about LINQ to SQL I am talking about LINQ (Language Integrated Query).  I think this distinction needs to be made in general as   statements like "LINQ is Dead" are erroneous and should read "LINQ to SQL is Dead".

Answer (score 6):

Ive become a fan of WCF: JSON/POX/SOAP...IPC, TCP, HTTP.  its enough to make a programmer involved in cross platform communication drool

Comment: Same here, although WCF was a 3.0 feature... you have my vote anyway because Slough is moving up from 2.0.

Comment: ya, but JSON came in 3.5, before that it required some real hacking around to get it to work.

Comment: You can return JSON in .NET 2.0 with ASP.NET AJAX Extensions 1.0

Answer (score 3):

WPF has some potential.

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in this topic and want to explore in some depth I very strongly recommend that you get a copy of Jon Skeet's [C# In Depth](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988363).  Every answer that you'll get here will be only part of the story whereas Jon's book walks you through C# 1 to 2 to 3 and shows you the application of new features in each release.

Update: The book is also available in O'Reilly's [Safari](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9781933988368?portal=oreilly).  It is really a read and ponder kind of book, though, so I think that you'll prefer the deadwood version.

Answer (score 2):

- lambdas
- All of the functions related to LINQ like .Where, .Except, .Intersect

C#-Centric...

- var keyword

  > ```
  > var name = "hello world";
  > ```
- Shorthand Properties

  > ```
  > public string Name {get;set;}
  > ```
- Coalesce

  > ```
  > bob = bob ?? 55;
  > ```

Comment: The coalesce operator has got nothing to do with .NET 3.5. In particular, it's a feature of the C# language and not of the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are not a big fan of Linq, are you speaking of Linq2Sql?  Because the capabilities of Linq2Objects is invaluable to me.  Ditto for Extension methods.  I can't go back, since using these features.  And, if you don't use Linq, all of the IEnumerable<> extensions in the Linq namespace are invaluable to me.

Not to mention all of the stuff you get with .NET 3.0 (WPF, WCF, etc)

3.5 is a HUGE step up from 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Extension Methods, Lambdas, Expression Trees.

Answer (score 0):

C# 3.0 language